# Why get empty roles from jwt token in spring boot security api

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am new for spring boot security and I am trying to develope an api with limit the access permision due to user roles. everything is fine but after i get jwttoken and if i convert it from online i get empty roles. any one know how to fix it ?

```
  @Slf4j
public class JwtTokenProvider {


    @Value("${app.jwtSecret}")
    private String jwtSecret;
//  public String generateToken(String username, UserNameWithRole userNameWithRole)
    public String generateToken(String username,Collection<String>roles){

        Instant now = Instant.now();
        Instant expiration = now.plus(7, ChronoUnit.DAYS);

        Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(username);
        claims.put("roles",roles.stream().map(s -> s.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        return Jwts.builder()
              //  .setSubject(userNameWithRole.getUserName())
                .setIssuedAt(Date.from(now))
                .setExpiration(Date.from(expiration))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
                .setClaims(claims)
                .compact();
    }

    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication){
        User user =(User) authentication.getPrincipal();//user fromspring framWork
       // user.getAuthorities()//roles
        return generateToken(user.getUsername(), user.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    public String getUserNameFromToken(String token){
        Claims claims = Jwts
                .parser()
                .setSigningKey(jwtSecret)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
        return claims.getSubject();
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String token) {

        try{
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token);

            return true;
        }catch (SignatureException ex) {
            log.error("Invalid JWT signature");
        } catch (MalformedJwtException ex) {
            log.error("Invalid JWT token");
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
            log.error("Expired JWT token");
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException ex) {
            log.error("Unsupported JWT token");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            log.error("JWT claims string is empty.");
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

user model

```
@Entity
@Data
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();


}
```

role model

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Role {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;


}
```

the screenshort of postmen getusers

[image]

the result of jwt after convert it

[image]

my token eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJkYXJ2aWQiLCJyb2xlcyI6W119.Uf5W_zZqXapwV7Pj6JM47RkrrVbdMoGduOPYnE4V5VPXpi02ODVVGRT0DtaVst66dgiXw2NuKeJuG9NUVDsfjA

Comment: because roles is a custom claim and not part of any standard claim so you have to parse them manually. And you have strangely chosen to write your verification of JWTs without using the built in tools that spring security provides, why you would do that i have no idea. I strongly recommend that you read the _resource server_ chapter in springs documentation, or you can read this https://thomasandolf.medium.com/spring-security-jwts-getting-started-ebdb4e4f1dd1 and implement the verification of JWTs correctly

Answer (score 0):

after i modified the generateToken

```
  public String generateToken(String name){

        Set<String> Userroles = new HashSet<>();
        com.security.demo.user.User  userOne = userRepository2.findByUsername(name);
        for(Role role:userOne.getRoles()){
            Userroles.add(role.getName());
        }

        Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(name);
        claims.put("roles",Userroles);

        Instant now = Instant.now();
        Instant expiration = now.plus(7, ChronoUnit.DAYS);


        return Jwts.builder()

                .setIssuedAt(Date.from(now))
                .setExpiration(Date.from(expiration))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
                .setClaims(claims)
                .compact();
    }
```

after convert jwt

[image]